# Does the gerund clause 'finding money' indicate passive meaning?

Tags: gerunds

1.It wasn't easy **Finding** **the** **money**.

in The gerund clause above sentence, Does it have a **passive** **meaning**?
like,'money being found'

Answer (score 2):

> It wasn't easy **finding** the money.

We may rephrase the sentence as

> **Finding** the money wasn't easy. ("What wasn't easy?" - "Finding the money.")

Meaning, "the process of finding the money was not an easy process". So there's no passive meaning there.

The **it** in the beginning of your ogirinal sentence is used for additional emphasis and could be omitted. "**It**" basically equals "**finding the money**".

Sentences of this kind are called "[cleft sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence)". You can read up on them in M.Swan's "Practical English Usage", Topics 130 and 131. Or probably it is the so-called "[extraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition)" (kudos to F.E. and his remark).

We can also rephrase your original sentence as

> It was not easy **to find the money**.

Comment: "**smoking** **cigarettes** is bad for you" Here,what does the gerund clause mean? (Does it mean 'the action that the cigarettes is smoked)

Comment: The meaning is closer to "the repeated action" or "the habit of smoking cigarettes", because "cigarettes" is in the plural. But yes, it basically means "if you smoke cigarettes (or a cigarette), this action of smoking causes you harm".

Comment: @Dinusa:  this is most often a figurative use of "find". People are not actually searching for hidden money. They are trying to find a way to afford to pay for something when they are on a limited budget. So the underlying concept is of the *effort* of those who are seeking to save or acquire the money, rather than the money sitting somewhere waiting to be found.  Money is the direct object of the *finder's* efforts to *find*.

Answer (score 1):

"Finding the money" or "smoking cigarettes" is in the longest form " the finding of money" or "the smoking of cigarettes" and I don't see anything that suggests the idea of passive. As such structures are based on verbs with an direct object it is technically possible to make up a passive formula but I have never associated "finding the money" or "smoking  cigarettes"  with passive.

A sentence such as "Cigarettes being smoked are bad for your health" has the same meaning, that's true, but it is a very unnatural way to express the idea. In fact, it is cumbersome.